# На месте ли слово "квест" в этом тексте?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Оказаться в этом зале квест, поэтому информация ниже полезна только
>   тем, кто действительно *маньяк* и готовит свои путешествия заранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Википедия говорит:

> Квест — задание в ролевых играх [ролевые игры не обязательно должны быть компьютерные — grizzly], которое требуется выполнить персонажу
>   (или персонажам) для достижений игровой цели.

Да, это слово вполне подходит по смыслу. В орфографическом словаре оно тоже есть — значит, его можно использовать хотя бы на правах жаргона.

Comment: Для меня *Оказаться в этом зале квест* звучит как *Оказаться в этом зале кранты*. Я роли слова в предложении не понимаю.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Надо бы тире поставить, наверное. Роль слова в данном случае — примерный синоним выражения "сложная задача".

Comment: А для меня звучит как бессмысленный перевод из гугла. "Квестами" сейчас именуют аттракционы, связанные с ориентированием в замкнутом пространстве и выполнением интеллектуальных заданий для получения ориентиров. Как минимум, перед этим словом нужно тире, но и тогда трудно понять, какой социальной группе принадлежит жаргон. Проще выразиться по-русски ("Попавший в этот зал бывает озадачен" и т. п.).

Comment: @Alex_ander Тире конечно нужно. *"Попавший в этот зал бывает озадачен"* — здесь Вы неправильно расшифровываете смысл слова "квест"; правильнее в этом ключе было бы сказать "стремящийся попасть в этот зал бывает озадачен" (в оригинале "задача" состоит именно в том, чтобы попасть в зал). Я уверен, что дальше по контексту даётся информация о том, как в этот зал попасть.